# How can I store an efficient table of static class types, and dynamically call methods of these classes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, class

I'm working on a client-server application which transmits a "command" from one endpoint to another.  I want this command to essentialy be an index into a table of class types which can be dynamically created to perform tasks as the commands come in.

I need to store references to a large number of worker classes (~4096 of them) in the most efficient way possible.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A bit more detail would helpful.

Comment: Ok my title is a bit misleading.  Say I wanted to store "references" to a large number of static classes that would perform something when the command was receivied, for instance, send a file back or perform some sort of task.  Say my TCP message contains 0x0001 as an index to this table I'm looking to create, I want to pull the class associated with that offset & execute it's methods.

Comment: Do you want to map a command to a class type, or a class instance? `Dictionary<string, Type>` not good enough for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using static classes, you might want to use a `Dictionary<int, Action<T>>` or `Dictionary<int, Func<T,T>>`

On startup populate the dictionary `MyDict[0x0001] = StaticClass.StaticMethod"`

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was looking for.  Now is this a bad idea performance wise?

Comment: @slashp Not as much as using reflection. Test it and see if the performance is good enough for your case

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate everyone elses answers too.

Comment: Ha! Have fun with memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary (Key/Value pair or even just an simple array) of an interface type

IMyCommand

and when the command index comes in, just invoke the Execute() method on the interface (or whatever you choose). Of course this requires you instantiate the objects before hand which might not be smart memory wise.

Otherwise, store the fully qualified type name and use reflection to instantiate that type as IMyCommand and then run Execute() method.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `Dictionary<string, ICommand>`, or something similar.
For more details, please supply more detail.

If you need to create a new class instance every time, use a `Dictionary<string, Func<ICommand>>`.